# How can i use interface pre-up/post-up/pre-down/post-down in ClearOS (CentOS-based)?

Tags: interface, centos

I need to execute some commands before and after my interface get up and get down. How can i do it in the ClearOS (it is based on CentOS), where there are not these options?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for here is the `/sbin/ifup-pre-local`, `/sbin/ifup-local`, `/sbin/ifdown-pre-local` and `/sbin/ifdown-local`.

All scripts take the device as the first argument. The `/sbin/ifup-pre-local` also takes a second optional argument which could "boot" when the interfaces are being brought up on boot.